# One Prop Confidence Interval in R Confusion: CI Starts with 0

Tags: r, zero, confidence-interval, p-value

I am doing a proportions test and the output has a p-value that is significant but a CI of [0.00, 0.11]

I am confused because I thought if it captured zero the difference was not significant. Is this not true in this instance or if the CI starts with zero?

Thank you in advance for any help/clarification you can provide.

I'll include the code below:

```
propt <- prop.test(0.326087, 45, p= 0.21, alternative = "two.sided")
propt
```

> 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction
>
> data:  0.326087 out of 45, null probability 0.21   X-squared = 9.9621,
>
> df = 1, p-value = 0.001598   alternative hypothesis: true p is not
>   equal to 0.21
>   95 percent confidence interval:
>    0.0000000 0.1096471
>   sample estimates:
>             p
>   0.007246378

Comment: *if it captured zero the difference was not significant.* Why? If you are testing a parameter that can only take values in `[0, 1]` the CI *must* be in that interval (and 0 is in the interval).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to set the number of successes to 0.326087.  Typically the first argument would be an integer value if it is a single number.  But the test you did is whether the proportion is equal to 0.21, which is well outside your CI.